# Ordered Binary Tree of Strings

Tags: binary-search-tree

These values are entered into an ordered binary tree: `Mercury`, `Venus`, `Earth`, `Mars`, `Jupiter`, `Saturn` and `Uranus`.

The resulting binary tree is supposed to be this.

```
          Mercury
        /         \
    Earth         Venus
       \           /
      Jupiter   Saturn
         \        \
        Mars     Uranus
```

Is there any reason for this order? Shouldn't Jupiter be under the Venus branch?

Comment: The given tree is incorrect for the given insertion order - `Mars` should be a right child of `Earth` and `Jupiter` should be a left child of `Mars` because the `Jupiter` node won't exist when inserting `Mars`. See this question for the correct ordering - [Binary Search Tree of Strings (before balancing)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20554826).

Answer (score 1):

By "ordered binary tree", I assume you mean a binary search tree. As long as the tree satisfies the following criteria:

```
1. The key in a node is greater than (or equal to) any key stored in its left subtree.
2. The key in a node is less than (or equal to) any key stored in its right subtree.
```

then the exact structure of the tree depends on the order in which the keys are added and the exact algorithm used to construct the tree.

However, you indicate that you believe that Jupiter should occur in the subtree of Venus. What is your ordering criteria? The tree you show is valid if the names are being compared alphabetically.

Comment: I see, that I was what I am wondering if they are ordered alphabetically or just random inserted into the tree. I take it its done by alphabetical order.